# How to use a computed property in fluent validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluentvalidation

I am currently using a dto which has a few fields as below:

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; } 
   //Other properties
}
```

I have a fluent validator the above dto.

My question is how do I add conditional validation for the above `FirstName` and `LastName` properties alone. The validation should be based on a `boolean` property (`IsEnabled`) which is got from an api call.

I need something like

```
public class PersonValidator
{
    When(profileAdd => {**IsEnabled**}, () =>
    {
       //Validations for first name and last name
    }
}
```

I read from github that parameters cannot be passed to the validators. So, how do I achieve this?

Comment: You cna use Must...RuleFor(r => propertyname)
  .Must((obj, i) => CheckIsEnable())
  .WithMessage("Error");

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
        When(x => IsEnabled, () => {
            // validation for first and last name
        });
```

---

or this:

```
RuleFor(person => person.FirstName).SetValidator(new YourCustomValidatior()).When(x => isEnabled);
RuleFor(person => person.LastName).SetValidator(new YourCustomValidatior()).When(x => isEnabled);
```

where "YourCustomValidator" will validate your property.
Learn more about custom-validator form here. (https://fluentvalidation.net/custom-validators)

You can also use built-in validators. (https://fluentvalidation.net/built-in-validators)